# Bash call a function in a command

Tags: bash

I have a question regarding the usage of functions in a command in bash. `getRegex` is my function, it is defined at the end of the the file. The command that I want to use is the following:

```
COUNT=`grep -rnE 'getRegex' $HOME/new`
```

Now I tried a lot of different variants but I cannot make it work, even if I split it in 2. The method works correctly if I call it the following way: `getRegex`. Any idea what I am missing? TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key words to answer are ["bash command substitution"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), which you could find in `man bash` or google.

By the way, double quotes are really important here.

```
#!/bin/bash

function my_func () {
    echo "no"
}

string="no you don't
no you don't
no you don't
no you don't
no you don't"


COUNT="$( echo "${string}" | grep "$( my_func )" -c )"
echo "${COUNT}"
```

And

```
$> ./ok.sh 
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to call a bash command within another bash command, the inner command (here getRegex) needs to be enclosed in backticks ``` `` ``` or else it will be interpreted as text. Since you here would have backticks inside backticks, you'll need to escape the inner ones. Try this:

```
COUNT=`grep -rnE '\`getRegex\`' $HOME/new`
```

But, through the wonders of POSIX, we can use a different syntax. Anywhere you use backticks, you can also use `$()`. So to avoid backslash emesis, you could write:

```
COUNT=$(grep -rnE '$(getRegex)' $HOME/new)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but: `COUNT=$(grep -rnE '$(getRegex)' $HOME/new)` returns: `line 10: getRegex: command not found`.

Comment: @Dan, did you check out what your code is really done? Are you sure about single quotes in second example?

Comment: dmalikov is, of course, correct, those should be double quotes, as single quotes in bash don't expand variables.

Comment: @user1020822, that error message directly contradicts your question. Please edit your question to show us what `getRegex` actually is.